# Как вычислить abs без использования стандартной функции языка

Tags: любой-язык, числа

Как найти модель целого числа без встроенной функции. Меня интересует необычные решение без использования `if`'а, а такое которое использовало особенности языка

пример оформления:

## Python

```
def abs(n):
    return n if n > 0 else -n
```

Comment: В чём суть вопроса-то? Ответ на Python вы сами написали прямо в тексте вопроса, какие пояснения ещё требуются? Если хочется собрать коллекцию примеров на разных языках — это получается слишком общая и бесполезная мусорка, которая должна быть закрыта. Если что-то другое, то это должно быть чётко обозначено в тексте вопроса с пояснением, чем этот пример на Python не угодил.

Comment: «такое которое использовало особенности языка» — любого языка? Тогда нужно уж доводить вопрос до формата соревнования, определять критерии победы и конкретизировать условия задачи (например, что конкретно считается или не считается if'ом?). А до тех пор это всё ещё слишком общий вопрос, в котором ещё и непонятно чем if не угодил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C, C++**

```
return (a < 0) ? -a : a;
```

---

```
if (a < 0) return -a; else return a;
```

А вообще задача некорректна - не указано, например, для целых чисел, нет... Например, для `int` сработает такой хак -

```
return ((a >>30)|1)*a;
```

**MASM**

```
cmp eax,0
jge label
neg eax
label:
```

Тряхну стариной :)

**Pascal**

```
function abs(a: real): real;
begin
    if a < 0 then 
        abs := -a
    else
        abs := a;
end;
```

Comment: Думаю, что список ЯП в заголовке можно существенно расширить

Comment: @vp_arth Можно. Но я с ними знаком не очень, так что...

Comment: можете пожалуйста объяснить как работает `return ((a >>30)|1)*a`

Comment: Знаковый сдвиг. Младший бит делаем 1, а знаковый остается. Т.е. по сути получаем -1, если знаковый бит был установлен, и 1, если нет. И умножаем на число...

Answer (score 5):

**Haskell**

```hs
abs x = x * signum x
```

или просто

```hs
abs = (*) <*> signum
```

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить о необычных способах,то на c++ можно написать так :)

```
int abs(int a)
{
    string str = to_string(a);
    if(str.find('-') != string::npos)
        str.erase(str.find('-'), 1);
    return std::stoi(str);
}
```

P.S. конечно можно было просто удалить первый символ, но так не интересно)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.x., 3.x.

```
def my_own_abs(x):
    return x if x > 0 else -x
```

## Python 3.9

```
def my_own_abs2(x):
    return int(str(x).removeprefix('-'))
```